# How to extract variable from within a function in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a program which scrapes bus information from a server and sends it to a user via Facebook messenger. It works fine, but I'm trying to add functionality which splits really long timetables into separate messages. To do this, I had to make an if statement that detects really long timetables, splits them and calls the `send_message` function from my main file, `app.py`

Here is the part of the function in `app` with the variable I need to extract:

```
for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:

                if messaging_event.get("message"):  # someone sent us a message

                    sender_id = messaging_event["sender"]["id"]        # the facebook ID of the person sending you the message
                    recipient_id = messaging_event["recipient"]["id"]  # the recipient's ID, which should be your page's facebook ID
                    message_text = messaging_event["message"]["text"]  # the message's text
                    tobesent = messaging_event["message"]["text"]

                    send_message(sender_id, fetch.fetchtime(tobesent))
```

and here is the if statement in `fetch` which detects long messages, splits them and calls the `send_message` function from the other file, `app.py`:

```
if len(info["results"]) > 5:
            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(info, 5), 1):
                app.send_message((USER ID SHOULD BE HERE, 'Listing part: {}\n \n{}'.format(i, chunk)))
```

I'm trying to call the `send_message` function from `app.py`, but it requires two arguments, `sender_id` and the message text. How can I go about getting the `sender_id` variable from this function and using it in `fetch`? I've tried returning it and calling the function, but it doesn't work for me.

EDIT:error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bus.py", line 7, in <module>
    print fetch.fetchtime(stopnum)
  File "/home/ryan/fb-messenger-bot-master/fetch.py", line 17, in fetchtime
    send_message((webhook(),'Listing part: {}\n \n{}'.format(i, chunk)))
  File "/home/ryan/fb-messenger-bot-master/app.py", line 30, in webhook
    data = request.get_json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Comment: We don't understand your problem.

Comment: Do you get error message ? Always show it. Add full error message in your question.

Comment: How do you call in `app.py` code from `fetch.py` - `fetch.some_function(...)` ? Can't you call `fetch.some_function(sender_id , ...)` ?

Comment: @furas I use `from app import *` - I'm trying to call the `send_message` function inside `app` from `fetch`

Comment: @furas I added the error.

Comment: but how do you use `fetch` in `app` - `import fetch` ? and `fetch.some_function(...)` ?

Comment: I use `fetch.fetchtime(number sent by user)` - this takes the user's bus stop number and fetches the timetable information for that number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124746/discussion-between-ryan-werner-and-furas).

Comment: can't you run it `fetch.fetchtime(number sent by user, sender_id)` and then use `sender_id` inside this function ?

Comment: @Furas I feel like an idiot, don't know how I didn't see that! Thanks a bunch!